# How to draw this figure in latex, using same arrows and braces?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

[image]

I need code to draw this figure in latex

Comment: Hey Parul. Can you provide some minimal document showing what you've tried?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[brace1/.style={decoration={brace,amplitude=7pt},
        decorate}]
        \foreach \x in {-5,...,5}{%Change the variation
        \draw (\x,0.2) -- (\x,-0.2);
}
        \node[anchor=north] at (-6,-0.6) {};
        \node[anchor=north] at (6,-0.6) {};
        \draw[<->] (-6,0) -- (6,0);
        \draw[brace1, line width=0.2mm] (0.1,0.5) -- (4,0.5) node[above] at(2,0.75) {Two}; %Change name
       \draw[brace1, line width=0.2mm] (-4,0.5) -- (-0.1,0.5) node[above] at(-2,0.75) {One}; %Change name

       \node[below] at (0,-0.1) {${t_{a}}^{0}$};

       \node[below] at (4,-0.1) {${t_{a}}^{m-1}$};
       \node[below] at (5,-0.1) {${t_{a}}^{m}$};

       \node[below] at (-4,-0.1) {${t_{a}}^{-(m-1)}$};
       \node[below] at (-5,-0.1) {${t_{a}}^{-m}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but why loading `pgfplots`? Instead of loading a whole additional package, maybe just load `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}`.

Comment: sorry it is customary to charge the package @JasperHabicht

Comment: It is also fine to load `pgfplots`, but you don't need to load `tikz` then and you should always set `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` (or similar) as the warning reminds you if you omit it.